# Entity Framework pass a complex type parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is defined with custom input type because I need to send there whole grid. For example something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE members_table_type AS TABLE
(
    mem_username VARCHAR(25),
    mem_firstname VARCHAR(25),
    mem_lastname VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE STORED PROCEDURE insert_members
    @members members_table_type
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.members 
    (mem_username, mem_firstname, mem_lastname)
    SELECT mem_username, mem_firstname, mem_lastname FROM @members;
END
```

And I'm using Entity Framework and if I update my model from database, then this procedure does not have input parameter..

Is there a way how to do it using Entity Framework?

I found a working solution using ADO.NET but I don't want to mix technologies for database communication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Entity Framework does not support table value parameters.

Here is a possible solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/29bcd888-6d79-4f60-8858-3a11a650018b/

Check if it's good for you...basically it uses XML and then converts the xml into something that can be selected.

Regards